# Show that semi-symmetric graphs are bipartite

Tags: graph-theory

Any of the resources I've searched up have claimed that this is a trivial proof, but I just can't seem to see it. I've also seen the claim on wiki that all edge transitive graphs are bipartite, I'm not convinced that is true.

Comment: If a graph is edge transitive but _not_ vertex transitive, it's bipartite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plan:

1. Let $G$ be the group of automorphisms of a semi-symmetric graph, $V$ the set of its vertices. Then $G$ has exactly two orbits in $V$.
2. If two vertices belong to the same orbit, they cannot be connected by an edge.

*PS:* as for the claim that all edge-transitive graphs are bipartite, this is false. A triangle is edge-transitive but not bipartite.

Comment: I'm still having a bit of trouble understanding, I hope my thought process is right. 

I can see how an edge in the same orbit would cause the other edges to not be transitive (Unless all the vertices in the orbit are connected with each other in which case we will eventually get the complete graph) so this makes sense.

I can see because G is not vertex transitive we need more than one orbit, but why not more than two? 

Is the 1st part necessary? I feel like I can just choose one orbit as one part and group all the other orbits into the other

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Azhuang Looks like you're right, it's not necessary to prove that there are exactly two orbits. Still, it is true. It is easy to see from edge transitivity that for each edge $(u,v)$ and for each orbit $X$ either $u$ or $v$ belong to $X$, and from this it follows that there are at most two orbits.

Comment: Ah thanks! It makes the proof much easier to explain with two orbits.